# How to use one AJAX handler for multiple purposes with callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a piece of code written in an object. You can see there is a `customers` object with a function for adding a new customer and a method for making AJAX calls

```js
var sys = {
  customers: {
    addNew: function(ref, cb = null) {
      if (!cb) { // so it can check if the call to this method was for requesting ajax request or handling its response . note i am sending the callback function reference same as the current
        core.request({
          d: $('form').serialize()
        }, 'sys.customers.addNew', ref);
      } else {
        if (ref.status) {
          $('.customers-list').append('<li>' + ref.customer.name + '</li>');
          alert('success')
        }
      }
    },
    updateRowAfterAdd: function() {
      // or i could use this for handling callback by passing its reference instead of the upper same function
    }
  },
  request: function(p = {}, c = null, e = false) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/to/my/server",
      data: {
        p: p
      },
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {

      },
      success: function(r) {
        if (c != null)
          (e ? eval("(" + c + "(r,e));") : eval("(" + c + "(r));"));
      }
    });
  }
}

$(document).on('click', '.addNew', function() {
  sys.customers.addNew($(this));
});
```

The idea in this example is to call the AJAX method by passing a callback function reference for handling the `success` response.

If you look at the `addNew()` method it is working in two ways. With the help of the second parameter, `cb`, it is determining that the call to this function was for sending an AJAX request or handling its response back.

I'm using `eval()` in the `success` callback which I know is **evil**, so I want to understand how I can do this without using `eval()`?

I have multiple things running on my page which need AJAX calls and I don't want to rewrite each of them.

I also need this for AJAX's `beforeSuccess()` method as well.

Comment: Instead of `eval`, just call the function: `c(r, e)`. This design seems weak in terms of [Is it wrong to use a boolean parameter to determine behavior?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior). The single-letter var names are hard to understand. If you don't mind providing more context, we can help you avoid an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i don't want to use the eval() . That is the major thing which i want to replace by any other present solution. 
And for Customer & Request in same place. Please do not consider it . Because i extracted this code just for making up this example . And for the boolean paramter part . I will look at it and try to make it more good.

I just want to get rid of eval() for now

Answer (score 0):

The design pattern you're using seems to be a needless abstraction which is causing more problems that it solves.

A better idea would be to have a central 'service' layer which makes the requests to your server side and handles the responses. If you wanted to abstract this further you could have other domain logic abstractions to handle AJAX requests and responses through a single class, however at that stage I would argue you're far better off using an existing framework to do this for you.

A strong recommendation would be to use Angular, given that its MVC pattern is where you're heading anyway.

If you did want to roll your own simplistic version, then a simple example would look something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addNew', function() {
  services.customers.save($('form').serialize());
});

// in a service layer JS file, far away from UI logic...
let services = {
  customers: {
    save: requestData => {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/to/my/server',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: services.customers.renderUi
      });
    },
    renderCustomerUi: customerData => {
      // optional: extract the UI update logic to your UI layer and pass in the callback as an argument
      if (customerData.status) {
        $('.customers-list').append('<li>' + customerData.customer.name + '</li>');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that i can achieve this in other frameworks .  But i wanted to solve this in the current code that i have with jquery and simple js.  And the solution that you have provided me . I've seen this before . But it wasn't helpful as in response i have fixed function handling . As i want to use dynamic function callback